# Bootstrap Switch - Change state after clicking on button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) plugin and Bootstrap Modal. Once the user clicks to change the Switch from `on` to `off` the Modal box fades in asking for a confirmation.

How do I change the Switch from `on` to `off` or from `off` to `on` only after the user clicks on Confirm button? If the user clicks on Cancel then the Switch should go back to `Off` status.

**[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/0owp23ug/2/)**

```
$("#myswitch").bootstrapSwitch();

$('#myswitch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {

    $('#showModal').modal({
     backdrop: 'static',
     keyboard: false
 });
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `state` method to prevent the switch from changing. Remember to use the third parameter to make sure the event is not executed again.

```
    $('#myswitch').bootstrapSwitch('state', !data, true);
```

Working example :

https://jsfiddle.net/hL0as0mv/169/

Full documentation : 
http://bootstrapswitch.site/methods.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's nearly there. How do I show the Confirmation modal before changing the status no matter if it's On or Off. In your example the Confirmation modal shows only when changing from Off to On. Sorry I should have mentioned that on the question, I just edited it.

Comment: @brunodd Sorry I thought that was what you wanted. Edited jsfiddle.

Comment: If you want the status to be set to off when ever user hits cancel  : http://jsfiddle.net/hL0as0mv/1/

Comment: Perfect! JSfiddle was perfect!